# Incorrect Height on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, fullscreen

A display issue has been reported on the iPhone. I do not have one. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas.

On my website. The trouble appears to be caused by the url bar. On android, the function `$(window).height()` returns (screen height - url bar). On iOS, it doesn't appear to be doing this.

On my site I am skipping the page down past the url bar. I am then making the images full screen and centered. ( I have to use Javascript because of some spec restrictions )

In Android, the images are resized to the visible area of the screen. On the iPhone they are resized to the available height - url bar. This causes the images to be too small with a gap at the bottom. At least this is my understanding of the problem.

iPhone Screenshots.

[image: with url bar]
*with the url bar*

[image: without the url bar]
*without the url bar*

This is what I am using to resize the images.

```
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
function setImageSize() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $('.photo-slide img').each(function() {
        var width = $(this).attr('data-width');
        var height = $(this).attr('data-height');

        if (width > windowWidth) {
            var ratio = windowWidth / width;
            width = windowWidth;
            height = height * ratio;
        }

        if (height > windowHeight) {
            var ratio = windowHeight / height;
            height = windowHeight;
            width = width * ratio;
        }

        var marginTop = 0;
        var marginLeft = 0;

        if (windowHeight > height) {
            marginTop = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
        }
        if (windowWidth > width) {
            marginLeft = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
        }

        $(this).css({
            'margin-left':marginLeft+'px',
            'margin-top':marginTop+'px',
            'width':width+'px',
            'height':height+'px'
        })
    })
}
```

Has anyone come across this before? How do I fix this so the image fills the screen when the url bar is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you call setImageSize() in a setTimeout set to something like 100 milliseconds, does the iPhone then give you the correct screen height? I recall this being an issue a while ago.

Alternatively couldn't you use window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') to check if it is an iPhone, and then add the URL bar height onto the image height?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add suggestions/troubleshooting as comments to the question, unless you have a definite answer to provide. See http://stackoverflow.com/about and http://stackoverflow.com/faq for more information.

Comment: Ok thanks, wasn't entirely sure how it worked, as I couldn't see a comment button or anything. I guess I don't have enough rep to comment directly to the question.